# Local Notification Vibrate until user action

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm incorporating Local Notifications into my app to notify the user when a certain event is happening, like an alarm.

Currently I have the Local Notification working with a sound and it vibrates.

What I'd like is to mimic the Alarm feature in the Clock app, when the user has their phone locked, it pops up a Local Notification style view and keeps vibrating until the user takes an action to stop it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The [UILocalNotification API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) lets you set the system default sound, choose a sound, or have no sound, and if you have some sound, it will vibrate under the right circumstances (i.e., the user has enabled vibration). But beyond that, you have no control over whether vibration occurs or how long it lasts.

Comment: The app "Purple VRS v2" uses repeating vibrations in its notifications. How does that app do it if it isn't possible?